# hello, I need a help to connect my spyder source code with excel sheet. first problem

Tags: python, excel, lstm, spyder, adam

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWMCh.png)

The future prediction part of the graph is strange. It's not predictable at all. The second question is, I want to import the data of the predicted part into an Excel file.

Comment: Where is the code? What is this graph? 
Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Incomplete question, please add more information